# Is there a difference between env / ENV and PORT / port in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, port

I'm new to Node.js and recently saw the following code used for the port connection :

```
process.ENV.PORT
```

And have also seen someone use `process.env.PORT` and even `process.env.port`. Now as far as I know JS variables and properties are case sensitives, so how come people are using different versions?

My IDE seems to recommend everything in lower case, so I'm curious, what I wish to know is :

- whether all of the above are valid.
- Why are they valid (JS is case sensitive)
- and is there a difference between any of them

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64473078/window-env-vs-process-env-vs-window-env-what-is-difference-while-using-in-vuejs

Comment: `env` is the environment where your nodejs is running. and PORT, port is the variable which is defined by the user for your program to access that and use it.

Comment: @insyri : not really

Answer (score 1):

Having `process.env.PORT` or `process.env.port` is up to you. You chose to call whatever you want your variable. And it is `process.env` in lowercase in Node's official doc. Here is the [link](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_env) if you wanna read it.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your questions:

*whether all of the above are valid.*
no, they are not. `process.ENV` is not the same as `process.env`. In fact the built-in `process` does not have an `ENV` property; so it is not valid unless you create a `process.ENV` property (wichi is a very bad idea btw)   **But** in windows `process.env.PORT` and `process.env.port` they are interchangeably valid

*Why are they valid* ?  because eventhough JS is case sensitive, the standard `process.env` property is, under windows, for cross-platform compatibility.

*is there a difference between any of them* ? `.env` and `.ENV` are different totally different `.ENV` does not even exist; on windows between `.port` and `.PORT` there is not any practical difference.

Comment: thanks, that explains a lot (wonder why someone was using `.ENV`).

Answer (score 0):

`process.env` is an object created by Node.js environment which contains some accessible internal keys and can be extended / edited programmatically. It means you can define or edit any properties you want.
So...

*whether all of the above are valid*
Both of them are valid because any key is valid (even `process.env.notReal`), which one to use is only your choice.

*Why are they valid (JS is case sensitive)*
Sure, JS is case sensitive, so `process.env.PORT` *is not* the same as `process.env.port` - they are two different properties. Variable naming policy is up to you.

*and is there a difference between any of them*
I guess you already got the answer, it's just a code style.